# Relative consistency proofs using proper class models

Tags: soft-question, set-theory

Are there any easy relative consistency proofs in set theory that can be done using proper class models, rather than set models?

The only easy one I can think of is proving the consistency of $\mathsf{ZF}$ relative to $\mathsf{ZF} - \text{Foundation}$ using the class $\text{WF} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \text{Ord}} V_\alpha$ of well-founded (*i.e.* hereditary) sets.

The next ones I can think of are the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ relative to $\mathsf{ZF}$, using $\text{L}$ or $\text{HOD}$, and the consistency of $\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{CH}$ relative to $\mathsf{ZF}$, using $\text{L}$. But these are a bit harder.  Are there any more that are as easy as the one using $\text{WF}$?

---

EDIT: By "easy" here I mean that it does not involve encoding formulas as natural numbers, or formalizing the satisfaction relation.  I consider showing one theory to be consistent relative to another theory using proper class models and relativization to be easier than proving formalized consistency statements using set models and the formalized satisfaction relation. For this reason, I am teaching it first in my class.  However, this advantage of using proper class models is nullified if I have to use the formalized satisfaction relation to construct $\text{L}$ or $\text{HOD}$.

Comment: You cannot do this for sentences $\sigma$ false in $L$, as if you could create a proper class model $M$ in $\mathsf{ZF}$ of $\sigma$, we could still create it in $\mathsf{ZF+V=L}$, but as $Ord\subseteq M$, $M=L$.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena Good point.  But perhaps one can still do something interesting where the desired sentence $\sigma$ is simply an axiom of $\mathsf{ZF}$ but we are only assuming some fragment of $\mathsf{ZF}$, as in the example with $\text{WF}$.

Comment: But there isn't much you can do, the other interesting axioms would be replacement and power set, but then again this cannot be done as $\mathsf{ZF-P}$ and $\mathsf{Z}$ are stricly weaker than $\mathsf{ZF}.

Comment: What do you mean by easy here, Trevor? "Does not involve forcing"? "Does not involve large cardinals"?

Comment: @CamiloArosemena Another good point.  But perhaps there is a sentence $\sigma$ that is true in $L$ but can be proven to be consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ by a method that is easier than constructing $L$?

Comment: Hi @Andres, I mean even easier than that. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Failure of choice in models with atoms.

Comment: @Asaf To do this without forcing, I'd need to assume urelements in $V$, right?  I will look into this.

Comment: Yeah. And you can also prove the consistency of urelements using classes. It's very easy to get it for set many urelements, but you can also get it for class many urelements.

Comment: @Asaf True. Also that makes me think of simply showing that $\mathsf{ZF} - \text{Extensionality} + \neg \text{Extensionality}$ is consistent relative to $\mathsf{ZF}$, which would be even easier.

Comment: Ignoring "easy", I think Camilo's comment reduces your question to what is true in L. But let me mention an interesting obstruction with HOD: Working in ZF, there is nothing beyond AC, that can be shown to hold in HOD, which doesn't already hold in ZFC. I cannot remember a reference for this but I sort of remember Arnie outlining a proof of this to Monroe and me in a cab ride.

Comment: @Trevor: That has set models in $\sf ZF$, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @hot_queen I have heard of that result too (or something like it, anyway.)  It surprised me at first.

Comment: @Asaf Yes, I only learned that recently.  I could just ignore those; it's fine if I don't get the optimal consistency strength results.  I could also show that $\mathsf{ZF} - \text{Power set} + \neg\text{Power set}$ is consistent relative to $\mathsf{ZF}$, _etc._ even though this is obviously not optimal.

Comment: Something which is not very difficult, but can be "less easy" is to show the consistency of anti-foundation axioms. If you start with models with atoms you can construct a permutation model in which foundation fails, and you have an exact control on how it fails. So you can show the consistency of anti-foundation axioms like that.

Comment: @Asaf I probably don't have time to do that in the class, I'm afraid.

Comment: The simplest, then, would be failure of choice or the existence of atoms.

Answer (score 2):

The relativized contructible universes $L[A]$ can be used to establish consistency results of the form: Con$(2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{n})$ implies Con $(2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_m)$ for any $0 < m < n < \omega$ - This maybe due to Hajnal, I don't have a reference.

Of course in the post-forcing set theory, these results seem nothing more than curiosities.

Comment: By "easy" I meant easier than $\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \implies \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{CH})$, although the comments convinced me that this is probably impossible.